# How to hardcode any variable with null or " " in xml?

Tags: xml, rest, atg

Below is my xml file for a custom Actor,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<actor-template default-chain-id="claimCoupon"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.atg.com/xsds/actorChain_1.0.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">


<actor-chain id="claimCoupon" transaction="TX_SUPPORTS">
    <form id="claimCoupon" handle="claimCoupon" var="claimCoupon" name="/atg/store/order/purchase/CouponFormHandler" 
    use-forwards="true" requires-session-confirmation="true">  
     <input name="couponCode" value="${param.couponCode}"/>
      <input name="applyCouponErrorURL" value="/model/atg/userprofiling/ProfileActor/error"/>
      <input name="applyCouponSuccessURL" value="/model/atg/commerce/promotion/CouponActor/claimCoupon-success"/>
    </form>
  </actor-chain>
 <actor-chain id="claimCoupon-success" transaction="TX_SUPPORTS">
        <output id="status" name="status" value="Success" />
    </actor-chain>


</actor-template>
```

If i want to hardcode couponCode to null,how should i do it???

Comment: what about "" a zero length string for attribute value?

Comment: tried that one also,but it didn't work

Comment: what error did you get?

Comment: **** Error      Mon Apr 11 13:05:51 IST 2016    1460360151441   /atg/dynamo/servlet/dafpipeline/ActorServlet    Error code: 500
**** Error      Mon Apr 11 13:05:51 IST 2016    1460360151441   /atg/dynamo/servlet/dafpipeline/ActorServlet            java.lang.NullPointerException
**** Error      Mon Apr 11 13:05:51 IST 2016    1460360151441   /atg/dynamo/servlet/dafpipeline/ActorServlet            at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.hash(U
nknown Source)